# Equivalent to NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-design

TL;DR Is there something equivalent of NULL, or some flag that can be used to treat it as NULL? Empty string can be set but doesn't seem correct(and Column can be of integer type).

I have a `Table1` which is like:

```
Table1 (Id (PK, NOT NULL), Col1 (NOT NULL), Col2 (NOT NULL), Col3)
```

In this only `Col3` can contain NULL value, others are required columns. Now I want to update an entry in this table, but it needs to be approved by someone, so I have another table `Table1Change` which is like:

```
Table1Change (Id (PK, NOT NULL), Table1Id (FK, NOT NULL), Col1, Col2, Col3)
```

Col1, Col2, Col3 can be NULL. If they have non-null value, that means it will replace the value of that column in `Table1`. So ApproveUpdate stored procedure will look something like:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Col1 = ISNULL(Table1Change.Col1, Table1.Col1),
    Col2 = ISNULL(Table1Change.Col2, Table1.Col2),
    Col3 = ISNULL(Table1Change.Col3, Table1.Col3)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table1Change ON Table1.Id = Table1Change.Table1Id
WHERE Table1.Id = @table1Id  
  AND Table1Change.Id = @table1ChangeId;
```

One problem with above approach is that suppose I have some value in `Col3` of `Table1` and now I want to delete it (and I should be as `Col3` can be NULL), in `Table1Change` just simply setting value to NULL won't work. As `ISNULL` will take original column's value.

So now to my question, is there something equivalent of `NULL`, or some flag that I can use to set the value for `Col3` in `Table1Change`, so if that is set stored procedure will make `Col3` in `Table1` NULL. Empty string can be set but doesn't seem good (and Col3 can be of integer type).

One other option that I know is, change the way `Table1Change` table is treated. New schema will look like:

```
Table1Change(Id (PK, NOT NULL), Table1Id(FK, NOT NULL), Col1(NOT NULL), Col2(NOT NULL), Col3)
```

Now if there is any update to a row to `Table1`, all data will be copied to `Table1Change` with updated field. Something like `(Col1, Col2, Col3)(oldValue, oldValue, newValue)`. Now the problem is solved as ApproveUpdate will just copy the whole record to the original table, so if newValue is NULL it will replace the existing value. But this will require a lot changes for me, so I'm keeping this as a last option. And if there is no simple way to change my current setup, I'm also open to other better designs for this type of use-case.

Comment: What's wrong with using `NULL`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - `Col3 = ISNULL(Table1Change.Col3, Table1.Col3)` - my read is that the underlying OP problem is detecting between when a column is to be blanked (Set to Null) and a column is not being changed (Null value against that column)

Comment: I want to update fields of one row with fields of other row. Now my current code only updates field of first row if there is non-null field in other row(see that sql code). This doesn't take in the case if i want to actually make a field in first row null using second row. So i cant use `NULL`

Comment: Exactly!!! Just like @Andrew said. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null can not be used to mean two things here:

- do not update the value
- set the value to null.

There are not 2 types of Null that allow you to distinguish between the 2 scenarios.

You will have to engineer around this, you could use some 'magic' values to denote blanking a field, although I'm not entirely keen on that option. (It does allow you to implement it without a table change, just proc logic change.)

You could equally add more columns to Table1Change, such as BlankCol1, BlankCol2, BlankCol3, as Boolean (bit) columns, and use that to denote if a value should be blanked.

Comment: Hey @Andrew, can you please give example of 'magic' value that can be used to denote `NULL`?

Comment: For an int, maximum negative value, for a string choose something random that can never otherwise occur such as `!!$#MAGIC#$!!`